# Unable to get first 10 messages using GMAIL api in JAVA?

Tags: java, gmail-api

I tried using .setMaxResults() for limiting the results to 10 but it fetches all results.

```java
public static List<Message> listMessagesWithLabels(Gmail service, String userId, 
                    List<String> labelIds) throws MessagingException, IOException{

    ListMessagesResponse response = service.users()
    .messages()
    .list(userId)
    .setLabelIds(labelIds)
    .setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(10))
    .execute();

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    while (response.getMessages() != null) {
        messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
        if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
            String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
            response = service.users()
            .messages()
            .list(userId)
            .setLabelIds(labelIds)
            .setPageToken(pageToken)
            .execute();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (Message message : messages) {
        System.out.println(message.getThreadId());
    }

    return messages;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with the Gmail API, but usually limiting the results means limiting the number of results **per page**. 
But you are actively fetching all pages. Just replace your while loop with

```java
if (response.getMessages() != null) {
    messages.addAll(response.getMessages());        
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: OMG!! it's working ....Thanks for the answer ...you made my day,man..;-)